# org.bluez.error.inprogress error with bluetooth

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I have an issue where the Bluetooth got disconnected after 1-2s of connection, the master side will show the following error:

```
org.bluez.error.inprogress
```

tracing to the log I saw it will enter the following func:

```
un 11 16:23:46 rap bluetoothd[21474]: src/device.c:search_cb() 00:0E:8E:8B:CA:9D: No service update
Jun 11 16:23:46 rap bluetoothd[21474]: src/device.c:device_svc_resolved() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_0E_8E_8B_CA_9D err 0
Jun 11 16:23:46 rap bluetoothd[21474]: src/device.c:connect_profiles() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_0E_8E_8B_CA_9D (all), client :1.394
...
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003903] bluetooth:l2cap_sock_release:1197: sock 0000000078f38a7c, sk 00000000f306c001
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap  kernel: [12110.003907] bluetooth:l2cap_sock_shutdown:1113: sock 0000000078f38a7c, sk 00000000f306c001
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003910] bluetooth:l2cap_sock_shutdown:1123: Handling sock shutdown
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003913] bluetooth:l2cap_chan_hold:489: chan 0000000093211dd1 orig refcnt 3
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003916] bluetooth:l2cap_sock_shutdown:1132: chan 0000000093211dd1 state BT_CONNECTED
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003921] bluetooth:l2cap_chan_close:732: chan 0000000093211dd1 state BT_CONNECTED
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap  kernel: [12110.003924] bluetooth:l2cap_chan_hold:489: chan 0000000093211dd1 orig refcnt 4
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003930] bluetooth:l2cap_build_cmd:2931: conn 000000003e9a2ca4, code 0x06, ident 0x05, len 4
Jun 11 16:23:49 rap kernel: [12110.003936] bluetooth:l2cap_send_cmd:865: code 0x06
```

and tracing to the code in blueZ:

```
static DBusMessage *connect_profiles(struct btd_device *dev, uint8_t bdaddr_type,
                    DBusMessage *msg, const char *uuid)
{
    struct bearer_state *state = get_state(dev, bdaddr_type);
    int err;

    DBG("%s %s, client %s", dev->path, uuid ? uuid : "(all)",
                        dbus_message_get_sender(msg));

    if (dev->pending || dev->connect || dev->browse)
        return btd_error_in_progress(msg);  <------------------ HERE
...
}
```

My question can I somehow know which condition (pending/connect/browse) is causing this error without adding editing the code as I dont have permission to do that ? and how come the blueZ will try to connect to the profile if any of this condition is in progress?

Comment: Try running "btmon" on another terminal as that might give you an insight as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the bluetooth service. Had an error that said the same and managed to solve it by restarting the bluetooth service.

```
sudo service restart bluetooth
```

Try running the above command and see if it helps.